# Integration Challenges: Electron, SQLite, and Python - Seeking Assistance

Tags: javascript, python, request, electron

I'm having difficulties integrating Electron with SQLite and Python in my application. The application has a window that saves data in an SQLite database and just then runs a Python script. Python execution is working as expected; however, saving to SQLite is not happening as planned.

Problem Description:

- The window is created successfully.
- The Python script runs correctly.

However, the event to save to SQLite does not seem to be working.

Code:

main.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');
const { Database } = require('sqlite3').verbose();

function createWindow() {
  const window = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
  window.loadFile('index.html');

  console.log('Window created.');

  // Handle the event to save to SQLite and execute the Python script
  ipcMain.on('saveAndExecute', (event, data) => {
    console.log('Receiving data to save to SQLite and execute the Python script:', data);
    saveToSQLiteAndExecuteScript(data);
  });
}

function saveToSQLiteAndExecuteScript(data) {
  console.log('Starting the operation to save to SQLite...');

  // Connect to the SQLite database
  const db = new Database(path.join(__dirname, 'mydatabase.db'));

  // Create a table if it doesn't exist
  db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries (text TEXT)');

  // Insert data into the table
  const stmt = db.prepare('INSERT INTO entries (text) VALUES (?)');
  stmt.run(data, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error inserting data into SQLite:', err.message);

      // Display the error log but continue with the execution of the Python script
      console.log('Continuing with the execution of the Python script...');
      executePythonScript();
    } else {
      console.log('Data inserted into SQLite successfully!');
      // Finalize the statement execution and close the database connection
      stmt.finalize();
      db.close();

      // Execute the Python script after successful SQLite operation
      executePythonScript();
    }
  });
}

function executePythonScript() {
  console.log('Executing the Python script...');

  const pythonExecutable = 'C:\\Users\\Gustavo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe';
  const pythonScriptPath = path.join(__dirname, 'hello.py');

  const result = spawnSync(pythonExecutable, [pythonScriptPath], { encoding: 'utf8' });

  if (result.error) {
    console.error('Python script error:', result.error);
  } else {
    console.log('Python script output:', result.stdout);
  }
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

renderer.js:

```
// Add the following at the top of the file
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');
  const saveAndExecuteButton = document.getElementById('saveAndExecuteButton');

  console.log('Page loaded.');

  // Add an event listener for the save and execute button
  saveAndExecuteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Save and execute button pressed.');

    const inputData = textInput.value;

    // Send data to the main process to save to SQLite and execute the Python script
    ipcRenderer.send('saveAndExecute', inputData);
  });
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello Python from Electron!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Python!</h1>
    
    <textarea id="textInput" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Type something..."></textarea>
    <br>
    <button id="saveButton">Save to SQLite</button>

    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My error log in the UI:

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at renderer.js:3:25

I don't know what else to do to make this work. Please help!

I've tried changing how to import and edit the execution order of functions, but I haven't had much success. My code only needs to create a database with the text received from the UI in the inputText and then execute the Python script. That's it, but it's not working at all!

OK, now my main.js is:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');
const { Database } = require('sqlite3').verbose();

function createWindow() {
  const window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  });

  window.loadFile('index.html');

  console.log('Window created.');

  // Handle the event to save to SQLite and execute the Python script
  ipcMain.on('saveAndExecute', (event, data) => {
    console.log('Received data to save to SQLite and execute the Python script:', data);
    saveToSQLiteAndExecuteScript(data);
  });
}

function saveToSQLiteAndExecuteScript(data) {
  console.log('Initiating the operation to save to SQLite...');

  // Connect to the SQLite database
  const db = new Database(path.join(__dirname, 'mydatabase.db'));

  // Create a table if it doesn't exist
  db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries (text TEXT)');

  // Insert data into the table
  const stmt = db.prepare('INSERT INTO entries (text) VALUES (?)');
  stmt.run(data, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error inserting data into SQLite:', err.message);

      // Display the error log but continue with the execution of the Python script
      console.log('Continuing with the execution of the Python script...');
      executePythonScript();
    } else {
      console.log('Data inserted into SQLite successfully!');
      // Finalize the statement execution and close the database connection
      stmt.finalize();
      db.close();

      // Execute the Python script after successful SQLite operation
      executePythonScript();
    }
  });
}

function executePythonScript() {
  console.log('Executing the Python script...');

  const pythonExecutable = 'C:\\Users\\Gustavo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe';
  const pythonScriptPath = path.join(__dirname, 'hello.py');

  const result = spawnSync(pythonExecutable, [pythonScriptPath], { encoding: 'utf8' });

  if (result.error) {
    console.error('Error from the Python script:', result.error);
  } else {
    console.log('Output from the Python script:', result.stdout);
  }
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

my renderer.js:

```js
// renderer.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');
    const saveAndExecuteButton = document.getElementById('saveAndExecuteButton');
  
    console.log('Page loaded.');
  
    // Add an event listener for the save and execute button
    saveAndExecuteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('Save and execute button pressed.');
  
      const inputData = textInput.value;
  
      // Use electronAPI to send data to the main process
      electronAPI.sendToMain('saveAndExecute', inputData);
    });
  });
```

and my preload.js:

```js
// preload.js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  sendToMain: (channel, data) => {
    ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
  },
  receiveFromMain: (channel, func) => {
    ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
  },
});
```

And I'm getting the log in the UI:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at HTMLDocument. (renderer.js:9:26)

Comment: You can try adding `webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true }` to your BrowserWindow options in main.js.  But preferred method would be to use a preload script: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload